# How do i force ffmpeg to keep sizes divisible by 2 while maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: ffmpeg

for example, this command line:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov -vf "scale=w=416:h=234:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease" -an -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 15 -
```

works fine except if the source video was 360x240, output will be 351x234. which kinda sucks as yuv420p video with odd sizes is difficult to handle due to the way colour data is stored.

is there a way i could force ffmpeg to give nearest possible even values?

Answer (score 5):

you can achieve that by using force_divisible_by=2 in your filter like this :

```
-vf scale=w=852:h=480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:force_divisible_by=2
```

i know the question is old but hope this help someone.

Comment: This answer is particularly helpful also due to the use of "force_divisible_by=2" because odd sizes do not generally work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're resizing use just one of the dimensions with an absolute value, example:

Change:

```
-vf "scale=w=416:h=234:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease"
```

To:

```
-vf "scale=w=416:h=-2"
```

Should scale to a width of 416 and scale the height appropriately so the aspect ratio keeps the same.

```
-2 = scale using mod 2
-4 = scale using mod 4 etc....
```